# Problem with save conflict when adding content type to list

Tags: content-type, event-receivers, feature-receiver

I have a feature receiver with the following code:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            SPSite site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;

            ProvisionHelper.SetContentType(web);
    }
```

and in SetContentType:

```
public static void SetContentType(SPWeb web)
    {
        using (SPWeb storiesWeb = web.Webs[Constants.SiteNames.Stories])
        {
            var stories = storiesWeb.Lists.TryGetList(Constants.ListNames.Pages);
            if (stories != null && stories.ContentTypes[Constants.ContentTypeNames.Story] == null)
            {
                SPContentType storyContentType = web.AvailableContentTypes[Constants.ContentTypeNames.Story];
                if (storyContentType != null)
                {
                    stories.ContentTypes.Add(storyContentType);
                    // Set the story content type to be the default one
                    SPContentTypeCollection currentOrder = stories.ContentTypes;
                    List<SPContentType> result = new List<SPContentType>();
                    foreach (SPContentType ct in currentOrder)
                    {
                        if (ct.Name.Contains(Constants.ContentTypeNames.Story))
                            result.Add(ct);
                    }
                    stories.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = result;
                    try
                    {
                        storiesWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        stories.Update();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        storiesWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

on `stories.Update()` I get the following error:

> "Save Conflict.
>
> Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web
>   browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

I have tried a few things with `web.Update(), web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true` etc but first time I deploy I always get the same error, if I deploy it again I don't get any error. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't see it right now.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your using statement to:

```
using (SPWeb storiesWeb = new SPSite(site.Webs[Constants.SiteNames.Stories].Url).OpenWeb())) {...}
```

Also try calling update just after adding the content type. Then REFETCH the 'stories' list and do your modifications and then call update again. 
I've had a similar problem when updating content types via powershell which involved getting the content type each time again otherwise I'd get the save conflict issues.